# Running apps on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have built the android emulator for **android-7.1.2_r17** from source code on my ubuntu 16.04 machine using the help from  [this](https://source.android.com/source/building) . I used 
`lunch full-eng` in the lunch combo. And the emulator launched.

Then, I downloaded .apk files (for example for a calculator app) and I could install these in the emulator using the command

`adb -e install -r "your-apk-file-complete-path"`

But when I try to run the app in the emulator by clicking on it, it shows the error: `Your app keeps stopping` and the app doesn't launch.

Can someone please help me run the app on the emulator?

Comment: Does the app run on a real device? Because this error message is usually related to an uncaught exception

Comment: Yes, its one of the standard apps that one gets from play store. Its not an app that I developed.